# submit custom form drupal 7

Tags: 7, forms

I've created one custom module to display product review form on custom created block but i'm not able to submit form and also I can't see form name while I checked with inspect element. give me solution please. 
Here is my code for it.

```
function my_module_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();

  switch ($delta) {
    case 'my_module_config':
      $block['subject'] = '';
      $block['content'] = my_module_form();
      break;
  }
  return $block;
}

function my_module_form($form, &$form_state) {

  $form['rating'] = array(
    '#type' => 'label',
    '#title' => t('Rating'),
    '#collapsible' => FALSE,
    '#collapsed' => FALSE,
  );

  $options = array(1 => t('1'), 2 => t('2'), 3 => t('3'),);
   $form['rating']['options'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Rating'),
    '#options' => $options,
    '#description' => t('Give your rating.'),
    //'#access' => $admin,
  );

  $form['comments'] = array(
    '#type' => 'label',
    '#title' => t('Comments'),
    '#collapsible' => FALSE,
    '#collapsed' => FALSE,
  );
  $form['comments']['prod_comments'] = array(
   '#type' => 'textarea', 
   '#title' => t('Comments'), 
   '#cols' => 60, 
   '#rows' => 5,
  );

  $form['submit_button'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit Review!'),
  );
  $form['#submit'][] = 'my_module_submit';
  return $form;
}
function my_module_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    drupal_set_message(t('The form has been submitted.'));
}
```

Comment: Is there any other submit form in this particular page?

Comment: Try with my_module_form_submit($form, &$form_state) instead of my_module_submit($form, &$form_state)..

Comment: HI,  Aparna,

Only one submit form in this particular page.

Comment: @ Abin,I tried with this.

Comment: @VirangJethva Any change..??

Comment: Nope, when I click on submit. page is not redirecting or loading. Abin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrote
$block['content'] = my_module_form();
which mean you called a function which return just an array.

You need to tell drupal that i am creating a form, for this use [drupal_get_form](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/7)

```
case 'my_module_config':
  $my_module_form = drupal_get_form('my_module_form');
  $my_module_form = drupal_render($my_module_form);
  $block['subject'] = '';
  $block['content'] = $my_module_form;
  break;
```

Comment: `$block['content']` can be a renderable array. It's a bit unnecessary to call `drupal_render`.

Comment: It depends on user, it may gives renderable array or direct html to content. see this https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7

Comment: "This may be a renderable array (preferable) or a string containing rendered HTML content". Render arrays are preferred.

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is here  in `my_module_block_view`

instead

```
      $block['content'] = my_module_form();
```

use

```
     $block['content'] =  drupal_get_form('my_module_form');
```

and also if it is not work instead of your submit handler add it to your action submit handler with

```
  $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'my_module_submit';
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add

```
$form['#submit'][] = 'my_module_submit';
```

your module ll automatically call the function

```
function my_module_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    drupal_set_message(t('The form has been submitted.'));
}
```

Comment: This should perhaps be a comment on the question as it doesn't provide a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

check out this [Advanced Form Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/afb)

you can add fields according to your requirement